# Стилизация строкового ресурса

Tags: android, android-resources

У меня есть строка:

`<string name="delete_file_dialog_text">Are you sure you want to delete the %s file?</string>`

могу ли я каким-то образом сделать жирным текст который находится в %s?

Варианты через spanable text и д.р. мне известны, вопрос стоит задать его только в xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно например сделать так:

```
 <string name="delete_file_dialog_text">Are you sure you want to delete the &lt;b>%s&lt;/b> file?</string>
```

и вытаскивая стринг из ресурсов показываем как html:

```
mytextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(sourceString));
```

[Вот тут описано](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#escaping_quotes) как обработать теги html

Comment: чучу-ть до этого не дошел. Спасибо! Только исправьте плз: <b> %s <b/> на &lt;b>%s&lt;/b> - по крайней мере с вашим вариантом не заработало, или добавьте как вариант.

Comment: @Valeriy, да вы правы) немного ошибся, нашел документацию по вашему вопросу, приложил в ответ :)